# didSelectRowAtIndexPath UISearchBar

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have searched answers for this question but I didn't find any relevant answers. In my table view when I touch one cell, a Detail View is pushed. Source code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"trajetDetail" sender:tableView];


}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"trajetDetail"]) {

    RechercheDetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    if (sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *destinationTitle = [[self.trajets objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
        [detailViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
    }


}
```

}

The question is that when users make a search with the UISearchBar (and UISearchDisplayController) that they could also touch the cell and be pushed to the detail view.

Sorry for my english and if it's not clear, just tell me I'll try to make it clearer.

Kindest regards

Comment: The question is unclear to me.  The normal behavior is that touching the cell should perform the segue to the detail view, regardless of whether or not a search has been entered.  Are you saying it's doing that and you don't want it to, or it's not doing that and you want it to, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

what wrong i see in your code is in your prepareforsegue method, you are selecting indexpath of standard tableView not the search tableview, this below line needs to be changed

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

the prepareForSegue would become something like this after the change

you should use this code instead

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"trajetDetail"]) {

    RechercheDetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    if (sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *destinationTitle = [[self.trajets objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
        [detailViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
    }


}
}
```

Comment: no... It works fine from the tableview but when I try with the search I have a SIGABRT signal.